# CS0246 namespace not found despite adding reference to System.Management

Tags: c#

I have added a reference to System.Management; It appears under references in solution explorer of my forms application. I have also changed the Target framework to ".NET Framework 4" from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" as suggested in another post on this subject. The statement "ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = objSearcher.Get();" works fine in a test console application I run, but fails with CS0246 in my forms application. I have done lots of research on this before asking this question and nothing I have tried works. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to remove and add the reference again after you switched the target framework version? Sometimes it also helps to restart visual studio...

Comment: Thanks JanDotNet, but it didn't work. ;

Comment: This can happen if you have a namespace or class that clashes with the namespace name.  For example, do you have a `Management` class or property?  Also, can you please add some code to the question?  Context can matter.

Comment: I restored Windows 10 from a backup image and tried again. Now it works. I had been using Windows 7 Ultimate. Perhaps Visual studio 2017 is better supported on Win10. Thanks for your helpful comments!

Comment: @jsnmf problems that solve themselves magically are the best kinds of problems to have.